# After upgrade pod Firebase to 4.8.0 version on iOS always getting a SIGABRT related with com.google.fira.worker EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, firebase, crash, cocoapods, sigabrt

After update my pods I am having problems with the version of firebase is always crashing my app at any time.

SIGABRT error xcode

[image]

Comment: When I downgrade to a previous version as 4.0.4  the app works good, any idea how to use the last version of  firebase pod ?

Comment: Are you using FirebasePerformance? See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/529

Comment: @PaulBeusterien thanks, Not I am not using FirebasePerformance I am waiting for new release from firebase team to try again.

Comment: Oh, it actually looks more like https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue upgrading to last version of Firebase 4.13.0. The problem was happening only with 4.8.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

this is your Answer 
I was stuck in the same issue for 4 days I downloaded firebase the issue was I name google play list as * GoogleService-Info-22.plist*. just remember don't put dashes rename it as GoogleService-Info.plist
GoodLuck!